# return a number with the first X bits set

Tags: functional-programming, clojure

what is a more efficient way to accomplish this in clojure:

```
(defn ones
  ([n] (ones n 1 1))
  ([n i res]
    (if (< i n)
      (recur n (inc i) (bit-set res i))
      res)))
```

preferably it should still "do the right thing" when it comes to numerical type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not take 2^(X-1) (by setting only the Xth bit) and then subtract 1?

Comment: That gives you the last X bits. ~(2^(width of type - X) - 1) will do it.

Comment: Oh, I see, I mistakenly thought by "first" he meant "least significant."

Comment: I do want the least significan bits. 
(ones 4) => 15

Comment: Will exponentiation really be faster than a sequence of bit-shifts?

Comment: the code for this is (defn ones [x] (- (bit-set 0 x) 1) thanks!

Comment: @Hank, yes, exponentiation of 2 can usually be assumed to be translated to bitshifts by the compiler.

Comment: Doh! It didn't register that the base was 2, even though that's obviously the only way for this to work.